# how to restart my program

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, application-restart

how to restart my program in assembly 8086. Operating system win 8.1  using emulator "emu8086".
when restart all variable contain previous data. I want to clear previous data and restart my program. please tell me the solution.

Comment: If you're running in an emulator, I don't suppose you can start a new instance of yourself. You might be able to read your own binary from disk so as to reset .data, restore the stack frame you had on entry, then jump to your own entry point. That sounds way too complicated to be practical, though.

Comment: is there any way to reset all variable??

Comment: Reading .data from disk.

Comment: How about the `HALT` instr ?

Comment: @Desolator How would that help ? HLT just stops the CPU until the next interrupt, no ?

Comment: simply i want to reset all variable.... but i am unable......

Comment: @tux3 If you are using windows, you can just `invoke ExitProcess, 0` with `invoke system, addr comm` which runs another instance.

Comment: @user3531583 WHY DO NOT YOU RESET ALL VARIABLES MANUALLY BY CALLING SOME PROC? YOU COULD FINISHED THIS TASK LONG TIME AGO RATHER THAN ASKING THIS QUESTION

Comment: @Desolator And things like invoking ExitProcess work from a 8086 emulator ?

Comment: @tux3 As I far as I know, it works only with `kernel32.inc` included

Comment: i have done ... i know this is not Good logic but i use in my project.... my all variable length "50 dup". 
i pick the offset and putting null "000h" in the variable using loop of 50 :p :D

Comment: this logic works fine... :)

Comment: '
reset proc
    mov cx,50

rr: 
    mov [bx],000h
    inc bx
    dec cx
    cmp cx,0
    je  re
    jmp rr

re:     
    ret
    
    reset endp

'